# Coffeescript array destructing ignore some value

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I'm using array destructing in coffeescript and it working properly:

```
[first, second, third] = [1, 2, 3]
console.log "First:" + first, "Second:" + second, "Third:" + third
```

but I want to be able to ignore array element. I want to do something like this:

```
[, second, third] = [1, 2, 3]
console.log "Second:" + second, "Third:" + third
```

This is possible in EcmaScript 6 but how to achieve this under Coffescript?

Comment: Anecdotal, but when I do regex replacements with a callback without care for the "whole match" argument, I write `string.replace(/regex/,function(_, capture1, capture2...) { ... })`. Using `_` as a "throwaway" variable name. Perhaps you could do the same with `[_, second, third]`? No idea if that helps :D

Comment: Тhanks for the comment. This is one idea but I prefer "real" ignore. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find how to do this. This can be done with expansion operator:

```
[..., second, third] = [1, 2, 3]
console.log "Second:" + second, "Third:" + third
```